# How to access artifacts from one job to another job?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a pipeline as below:

```
stages:
  - code-analyze
  - build
  - infra
  - integration-test
  - performance-test
  - teardown

.base:
  tags:
    - gitlab-runners-220707-195833-small

check-style:
  extends: .base
  stage: code-analyze
  script: ./gradlew styleCheck

build-code:
  extends: .base
  stage: build
  script: ./gradlew build -x detekt
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/A/build/libs/A.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/B/build/libs/B.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/C/build/libs/C.jar
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/D/build/libs/D.jar

build-infra:
  extends: .base
  stage: infra
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/assume_role.sh
  script:
    - . ./terraform/test_apply.sh -w ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build.env
  needs:
    - job: build-code
      artifacts: true

run-integration-test:
  extends: .base
  stage: integration-test
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/authentication.sh
  script:
    - . ./CI/.variables
    - ./gradlew integrationTest -D$API_INVOKE_URL -D$STREAM_ARN
  needs:
    - job: build-infra
      artifacts: true

run-performance-test:
  extends: .base
  stage: performance-test
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/authentication.sh
  script:
    - ./gradlew gatlingRun-com.simulations.FooSimulation -Dusers=500 -DbatchSize=500 -D$API_INVOKE_URL -D$AUTH_TOKEN
  needs:
    - job: build-infra
      artifacts: true

.teardown: &teardown
  extends: .base
  stage: teardown
  before_script:
    - . ./CI/assume_role.sh
  script:
    - . ./terraform/test_destroy.sh -w ${CI_PIPELINE_ID}

success-teardown:
  when: on_success # Run the job only when no jobs in earlier stages fail or have allow_failure true
  <<: *teardown

failure-teardown:
  when: on_failure # Run the job only when at least one job in an earlier stage fails. A job in an earlier stage with allow_failure true is always considered successful.
  needs: ["build-code", "run-integration-test", "run-performance-test"]
  <<: *teardown
```

The pipeline works as follows:

- If all the stages have passed successfully, success-teardown will
  execute
- If any of the "build-code", "run-integration-test", "run-performance-test" fails, then failure-teardown will execute

The problem is the teardown steps are terraform destroy steps which needs access to the jar files from build-code stage to successfully destroy the infrastructure. In both the teardowns artifacts from build-code are not downloaded. However If I do artifacts:true then it would also depend on build-code. I dunt want to trigger teardown if build-code step fails. Is there a more efficient way to achieve such kind of workflow?